# DSE 5.1.10 table with no columns.. Restart Error

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Facing Error while cassandra restart.

> ERROR [main] 2018-09-04 03:04:53,490  CassandraDaemon.java:723 -
>   Exception encountered during startup
>   org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace$MissingColumns: Columns not
>   found in schema table for test.test1
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchColumns(SchemaKeyspace.java:1120)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:1066)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:1009)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:963)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:940)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:928)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:93)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:83)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:263)
>          at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:481)
>          at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:617)
>          at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:93)

**Note:** This table was not created.

```
user@cqlsh:test> desc test1 ;

CREATE TABLE test.test1 (

) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

user@cqlsh:test> DROP TABLE test.test1;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table test1"
user@cqlsh:test>
user@cqlsh:test> SELECT * from test.test1;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table test1"
```

This issue occurs for multiple tables.. Some tables are not available in `system_schema.tables`.

DSE 5.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Run a rolling restart to ensure schema matches across nodes. after check that there is only one schema version.

Answer (score 0):

try out this step, this basically temporarily starts Cassandra by ignoring corrupted schema

```
cassandra -Dcassandra.ignore_corrupted_schema_tables=true
```